# Is it possible to pipe the output of EvaluationMonitor to Excel?

Tags: numerical-integration, evaluation, debugging, external-calls

I have an EvaluationMonitor setup to capture the points processed by NIntegrate.

This is a case where the same function, integrated over the same region in cartesian coordinates yields a dramatically different result when polar coordinates are used.

For example:

```
NIntegrate[f[x,y,z] Boole[x^2+y^2<0.2828427],{x, 0.1,.2},{y,0.1,.2},{z,0.6,1.4},
 EvaluationMonitor:>Print["x=", x " y =",y " z= ",z]]
```

returns 2.694

```
NIntegrate[f[r Cos[\[Theta]],r Sin[\[Theta]],z,],{r, 0.1,0.2828427},
 {\[Theta],0.0,\[Pi]/2},{z,0.6,1.4}, 
 EvaluationMonitor:>Print["x= ", r Cos[\[Theta]], " y= ", r Sin[\[Theta]] " z= ",z]]
```

returns 114.531

Is there a way to pipe the points from `EvaluationMonitor` to Excel so that I can see the difference in points used by `NIntegrate` to evaluate `f[x,y,z]`?

Comment: Well, are you sure it's _the same region_?: `Column@{RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 0.2828427 && 0.1 < x < .2 && 0.1 < y < .2, {x, 0, 0.2828427}, {y, 0, 0.2828427}], 
  ParametricPlot[{r Cos[\[Theta]], r Sin[\[Theta]]}, {r, 0.1, 0.2828427}, {\[Theta], 0.0, \[Pi]/2}]}`

Comment: @ user1585715: Yes, it is. Instead of using Print in your notebook you can collect the results of the evauation monitor in a list which you initialize to be empty (m={}) and then EvaluationMonitor :> AppendTo[m, {x, y, z}]. Then export the data using Export["c://temp//EvalM.txt", m]. Start Excel, open this file, and do the required post processing in Excel (removal of brackets; and if necessary, decimal point -> comma)

Comment: Dr. Hintze- Thanks most kindly!